# How to specify a style for the wrapper in jQuery Validate plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I have a responsive web app, and I'm validating a form with jquery validate.js, the thing is that I want the error message to be below the Input, so I use a wrap for that. This is the code:

```
    <script src="dist/jquery.validate.js"></script> 
<script>
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
        signupForm.submit();
    }
});

$().ready(function() {

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        wrapper: "div",
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            confirm_email: {
              equalTo: "#email"
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirm_password: {
              equalTo: "#password"
            },
            pais:       {required: true},
            pregunta:   {required: true}
        },
        messages: {
            alias:  {required: "Campo obligatorio"},
            email: "Use una cuenta de correo v&aacute;lida",
            confirm_email: 
            {
                required: "Use una cuenta de correo v&aacute;lida",
                equalTo: "Los correos deben coincidir"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Campo obligatorio",
                minlength: "La contrase&ntilde;a al menos debe tener 5 caracteres"
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: "Campo obligatorio",
                minlength: "La contrase&ntilde;a al menos debe tener 5 caracteres",
                equalTo: "La contrase&ntilde;as deben coincidir"
            },
            pais:       {required: "Campo obligatorio"},
            pregunta:   {required: "Campo obligatorio"},
            respuesta:  {required: "Campo obligatorio"}
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Then I want to aply some style this div wrap, How I do that?

Comment: [As per jQuery `ready` docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), `$().ready(function()...` is **NOT recommended**.  Use `$(document).ready(function()...` or `$(function()...` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [the `wrapper` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#wrapper) set to `"div"`, you'll end up with this markup for the error messages...

```
<div>
    <label class="error">Validation Error Message</label>
</div>
```

> Then I want to aply some style this `div` wrap, How I do that?

Simply use CSS to style...

```
label.error {
    /* your CSS rules */
}
```

---

However, if you want to target the `div` itself, then set [the `errorElement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorelement) to `"div"` (**instead** of `wrapper`)...

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
    errorElement: "div",
    ....
```

...to get this markup...

```
<div class="error">Validation Error Message</div>
```

Then use CSS to style...

```
div.error {
    /* your CSS rules */
}
```

Comment: @Artemination, that should really be posted as a whole new question since it has nothing to do with CSS.   Then you can explain in great detail how you expect it to work and show the code you've tried already.  However, look into using [the `errorPlacement` function](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) for a start.  View the plugin source code to find the default.